# Bearer token not generating and not setting to header in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

So I've been trying to solve the problem of my bearer jwt token not generating after a successful login. I tried many things to try to get my backend api to generate the token after the validation. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any answers would be much appreciated! Below, I have added my generator, validation and controller class for this issue. Feel free to ask about what other code snippets you would like to see.

```
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.config;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class JwtTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {
            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityContext.JWT_KEY.getBytes());
            String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                    .setIssuer("instagram")
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .claim("authorities", populateAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()))
                    .claim("username", authentication.getName())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000000000))
                    .signWith(key).compact();
            response.setHeader(SecurityContext.HEADER, jwt);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public static String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authorities = new HashSet<>();

        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authorities.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",", authorities);
    }

    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/signin");
    }
}
```

```
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.config;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class JwtTokenValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, @NotNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String jwt = request.getHeader(SecurityContext.HEADER);
        if (jwt != null) {
            try {
                jwt = jwt.substring(7);
                SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityContext.JWT_KEY.getBytes());
                Claims claims = Jwts
                        .parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();

                String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
                String authorities = (String)claims.get("authority");

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorityList = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities);
                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, authorityList);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/signin");
    }
}
```

```
package com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.controller;

import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.exception.UserException;
import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.model.User;
import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.repository.UserRepository;
import com.instacloneapi.instacloneapi.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<User> registerUserHandler(@RequestBody User user) throws UserException {

        User createdUser = userService.registerUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<User> signinHandler(Authentication authentication) throws BadCredentialsException {

        Optional<User> opt = userRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName());

        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(opt.get(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
    }

}
```